# Smooth scroll stopped working on Chrome, but still working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to figure out why smooth scroll stopped working on Chrome but the funny thing is that it working on Firefox so I lost my mind completely now. I was thinking that maybe .click function stopped working but it seems it working well or maybe I'm wrong? By the way, smooth scroll worked a few weeks ago correctly, now only scrollToTop works.

The page with the issue. [www.jc-kancelaria.pl](http://jc-kancelaria.pl)

Please be lenient because that's my first post here so if I did something wrong let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Mateusz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: console shows errors - so, that's a place to start

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is more picky about JS errors than FF. If Chrome runs into a JS error, it will usually just stop executing any script that is supposed to run after that error. In your case, you indeed have an error with your Google Maps script. Fix that first, and then test the smooth scroll again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Google map issue has been fixed but the problem with smooth scroll still exists. I noticed that if you open individual sections in new tab script will scroll or open in this section. No errors appear anymore so I don't know where to looking for. Any more ideas?